# How To reload same Jsp page from where user left off

Tags: jsp

How To reload same Jsp page from where user left off. For Example :-
User is at a download page, but downloading a file require user to Login. How to retain the web address from where user left off?

Comment: Just remember the current URL as request parameter or session attribute while clicking the login link/button?